# Adding Descriptions to UPS Methods?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, ups

I'm trying to output a description below each UPS method that appears on the list of available methods but can't seem to do it without the UPS module bugging out!

Currently in my alternative shipping extension I've defined a description and I'm outputting it into available.phtml as echo $_rate->getMethodDescription()

How would I go about defining a description for each UPS method in the default module? Ultimately I want to basically tell people the timescale based on the destination country they've entered.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty crude but you could pass the rates into a custom module just before they get rendered, iterate through them, and add in a description manually if the name regex matches UPS?